# Need an image editor to add text with simple font selection

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, image-editor

I need to add bookmarks as text to my images (if possible with certain levels of opacity), currently I have GIMP, Xpaint and Gnome paint drawing editor. But all these are not good for simply adding text and selecting its colour, bold / italic, font and location with ease.

GIMP does somewhat OK at this, but I felt it quite pro for such a basic function. I would like a simple tool which can add text on a image. I used Photoscape in Windows but I am avoiding WINE at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try pinta. It is in the repository.

Comment: Thanks, any tools which supports opacity ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use it daily

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the best tool when you speak about images, is Digikam. It's a great tool that allow you to do everything with you pictures.
To install this software, install the following package: [digikam](http://apt%3adigikam).

Comment: It seems photo management tool than editor. :(

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using terminal commands and [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/).

About halfway down the page is the watermarking tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Pinta, mtpaint and gnome-paint should all meet your definition and needs.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-paint pinta mtpaint
```

I would recommend starting with gnome paint, if you want something like ms paint. Mtpaint goes just a bit beyond that. Pinta is much more like paint.net

Answer (score 0):

I guess Shutter is what you need. You can take a screenshot or open an already existing image, go to internal editor and add your text with color, opacity font and font size that you want.

Other than that, on Linux you are basically down to just three other apps: GIMP, Krita and Inkscape.